# Use name from referenced user entity in URL as contextual filter

Tags: 7, views

In a D7 site, I have a blog node, and to allow multiple authors, I'm using a user entity reference field (field_source) for blog author instead of the default user. I would like to create an RSS feed of a referenced source's blog content with the URL friendly version of the source's name as a contextual filter (e.g. for user John Smith, the url would be /mysite.com/feed/john-smith).

Here's what I have so far in my view:

- Display type = Feed
- Relationship of "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity - A bridge to the User entity that is referenced via field_source"
- Contextual filter of field_source with settings of:

  - User validator
  - Allowed filter value of "Allow both numeric UIDs and string usernames"

My problem is, I can get it to work just fine with the uid (e.g. /feed/123), but not the name. As far as I can tell, I have added everything I should need.  What else am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What happens with "Only allow string usernames"?

Comment: With " Only allow string usernames", I still get no results. In fact, it looks like a query isn't even run, since none is displayed and I have the " Show the SQL query" option enabled in Views settings.